# ListView does not display the first row value

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

**UPDATE: PROBLEM FIXED** - 
The ActionBar was covering the first item on the list.

**SOLUTION:** [Android AppBarLayout overlaps listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32653767/android-appbarlayout-overlaps-listview)

In my program, I am retrieving data from the database and displaying it using List View.
However, the first row elements are always skipped in the process and the display begins from the second row.

```
public void displaydata(){
    Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.idListView);
    if(res.getCount() == 0){
        //show message
        return;
    }
    ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
    while(res.moveToNext()){
        buffer.add(res.getString(1));
    };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,buffer);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

How do I make it display from the first row?
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: I have tried all suggested answers of using a 'do-while' and a 'for loop', all of which give the same result.

Comment: I believe its because `res.moveToNext()` goes to the next row so index 0 gets skipped

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723770/whats-the-best-way-to-iterate-an-android-cursor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to iterate an Android Cursor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723770/whats-the-best-way-to-iterate-an-android-cursor)

Comment: You really should be using a CursorAdapter instead of trying to load everything into an ArrayList / ArrayAdapter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android AppBarLayout overlaps listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32653767/android-appbarlayout-overlaps-listview)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
while(res.moveToNext()){
        buffer.add(res.getString(1));
    };
```

to

Edit: change the while so it increments after:

```
do {
    buffer.add(res.getString(1));
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Comment: `do { ... } while (res.moveToNext());` is preferred to avoid repeated `getCount()` calls

Comment: @Derek Baxter That wouldn't work because I need to make 'res' point to the next data item using 'res.moveToNext'.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would recommend a `CursorAdapter` when using a database.

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.idListView);

String from = { COLUMN_NAME };
int[] to = { android.R.id.text1 };

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = 
    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
          myDb.getAllData(), 
          from, to);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: It says that 'SimpleCursorAdapter' is deprecated

Comment: Yes, that's true, but that doesn't mean this shouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try out this this code may be useful for fetching data from db using cursor.

```
  public ArrayList<BasicInfo> getFetchBasicInfo() {

    ArrayList<BasicInfo> data = new ArrayList<BasicInfo>();

    String sql = "select * from basic_info;

    Cursor c = fetchData(sql);

    if (c != null) {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            String FirstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("first_name"));

            String LastName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("last_name"));
            String Sabcription = c.getString(c
                    .getColumnIndex("salutation_id"));
            data.add(new BasicInfo(FirstName, LastName));
        }
        c.close();
    }
    return data;
}
```